# Multi tenancy project

Tags: asp.net, web, web-applications, hosting, multi-tenant

I have a website, that will work with multiple companies.
I need to have remote repository with project and I want to be able to create a separate copy of this project for each company and separate database too. Every company should have its own url like company_name.site_name.com.

This approach allows me to use for example one server for some big company and another server for several small companies.
So **is there any tools or frameworks** that can help me?

If it's important I use ASP.NET for website and SQL server

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx) if you're planning to use ASP.NET and SQL.  Just create a different branch for each company.

You can also use [SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) with the same approach.  Create different branch for each company.

You can merge your code in the trunk or main branch to keep a common project and each branch for company is a company specific codes.

There are a lot of repository tools out there.  These 2 are the most common.

Comment: It's not exactly what I search for. You suggested me Version Control Systems.  When the company registers  on my site copy of the project and an individual database should be automatically created . And then company should be able to use my site by url "company_name.site_name.com"

Comment: i see i miss understood your question. why u need to create a different database for each customer but instead just create a table for customers.  Don't you think it is costly to create a database for each customer with the same information?

Comment: Because if I one day want to move company from one server to another it would be very easy

Comment: hmm from my point of view and experience. working on ASP.NET and SQL, it would be wise and less expensive if all DB is in one server, but to answer your question, I would suggest to script out your database (tables, SP, sql-jobs etc) and re-create those once a new customer signs up.  Creating a subdomain is another thing.  I haven't heard or found a framework that would do that yet.  But the one I'm suggesting above can be done in Single Sign On. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa745042(v=bts.10).aspx